# Is there a place where we can find out the model numbers of parts used in vehicles

Tags: nissan

My car is Nissan Sunny N16. Its ODOmeter display is partially burnt (similar to what happens to a digital watch). When I went to the garage, they say I need to replace the whole dashboard meter board and the price seems to be too high. I was wondering whether I would be buy it from somewhere online. But I dont know the part name to search for (I have done lot of searching, but no luck).

Is there a place where I can look for such information or can someone help me on this?

Comment: See online parts catalogs ;)

Comment: Where can I find it. I tried searching with various keywords and failed.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found that an owners' forum for your specific make/model is the best source of information. FOr instance, here's a Nissan Owners Club from the UK: http://www.nissanownersclub.com/

There's always someone who takes things very seriously and can help you with just about any piece of information you require.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some part code on the back of dashboard, so you have to unscrew it. But there are not the thousands of different one, so the related information you already have. Just look for one for N16, your made year and engine ( HP and fuel type).

Comment: Are these available to buy online? Becasue, it seems unreasonably expensive in my country :(

Comment: I think ebay or so. Some shops with used car parts maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Modern instrument panels in modern vehicles are virtually a part/extension to the vehicles engine ECU. This is to prevent 'clocking' and other activities, like engine tuning. You could try for a replacement instrument from a vehicle breakers, but you may have problems installing it because a used panel may not be accepted by your vehicles ECU as the replacement instrument panel's Component Identity Number (CID) will be differant and will not work with the ECU. It all depends on how up to date your vehicle is with regards to  security. This may be the reason your repairer is saying that you have to have a complete board.